# Count rows based on a pair of distinct values

Tags: sql, hive

We use hive to run queries on AB test data. The problem here is that we have some duplicate data we are trying to ignore. Luckily we have a means to ignore duplicate data. Our conversion_meta column contains an indicator for this duplicate data.

I'd like to find `distinct (conversion_meta, conversion_type)`. I can't really figure out the correct syntax though. Here is what I have so far:

```
select conversion_type, day, sum(if(is_control='true', 1, 0)) as Control, 
sum(if(is_control='false', 1, 0)) as Test from Actions
where day > "2013-12-20" and experiment_key='xyz' group by conversion_type, day
```

The columns in the end result should look like:

Conversion Type, Day, Control (count), Test (count)

Comment: How does conversion_meta works?

Comment: @PeterRing its just a json blob, but it basically has 1 key in it for this case. In this case it only contains an order id. If the order id appears for multiple times for a single conversion type then it is duplicate. If there was a way to count only distinct meta and conversion type and group them by day that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem with union all.:

```
select conversion_type, day, sum(if(is_control='true', 1, 0)) as Control, 
sum(if(is_control='false', 1, 0)) as Test from Actions
where day > "2013-12-20" and experiment_key='xyz' and conversion_meta = false
group by conversion_type, day
UNION ALL
select conversion_type, day, sum(if(is_control='true', 1, 0)) as Control, 
sum(if(is_control='false', 1, 0)) as Test from Actions
where day > "2013-12-20" and experiment_key='xyz' and conversion_meta = true
group by conversion_type, day
```

Comment: Hmm well conversion_meta isn't true/false it's a json blob with an order id in it. That's the only thing in it. Soooo is there a good way  to find distinct conversion_meta/conversion_type and count them by day?